# 3d Chern-Simons TQFT of gauge group (E8)$_1$ = SO(16)$_1 \otimes$ a trivial spin TQFT = Cartan E$_8$ matrix

Tags: ct.category-theory, 3-manifolds, gauge-theory, conformal-field-theory, chern-simons-theory

In this post, we like to relate the following 3 bosonic TQFTs that can be defined on generic non-spin manifold $M^3$.

Given a non-abelian Chern-Simons (CS) TQFT of a gauge group $G$ and the $k$ named as the level, we name it as 3d $G_k$ CS TQFT.

We write its path integral formally as 
$$
Z=\int [DA] \exp(i S)=
\int [DA] \exp(i \frac{k}{4\pi}\int_M \text{tr}\,(A\wedge dA+\tfrac{2}{3}A\wedge A\wedge A)).
$$
with an action:
$$S=\frac{k}{4\pi}\int_M \text{tr}\,(A\wedge dA+\tfrac{2}{3}A\wedge A\wedge A).$$

The trace tr is taken as the trace of the matrix representation of the Lie algebra valued gauge field $A$. $A$ is a locally 1-form gauge field or 1-connection of the principle $G$ bundle.

1. > 3d (E$_8$)$_1$ CS TQFT

The first is a 3d Chern-Simons TQFT of for a gauge group $G$=(E$_8$) with a level $k=1$, written as (E$_8$)$_1$ CS TQFT.

2. > 3d SO(16)$_1$ CS $\otimes$ a trivial invertible spin TQFT.

This second one we start now with a 3d Chern-Simons TQFT of a gauge group $G$=SO(16) with a level $k=1$, written as SO(16)$_1$ CS TQFT.

Note that:

- 3d SO(16)$_1$ CS TQFT is a fermionic TQFT defined on a spin manifold.
- 3d Spin(16)$_1$ CS TQFT is a bosonic TQFT defined also on a non-spin manifold.

Since 3d SO(16)$_1$ CS TQFT is a fermionic TQFT that can be defined only on a spin-manifold,

I propose a tensor product it with a trivial spin TQFT.

i.e. "3d SO(16)$_1$ CS $\otimes$ a trivial invertible spin TQFT. "

3. > 3d Cartan E$_8$ matrix abelian U(1)$_8$ Chern-Simons theory

The $E_8$ Cartan matrix is given by,
$$
K_{E_8}=\begin{pmatrix}
 2 & -1 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 & 0 \\
-1 &  2 & -1&  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 &  2 & -1 &  0 &  0 &  0 & 0 \\
 0 &  0 & -1 &  2 & -1 &  0 &  0 & 0 \\
 0 &  0 &  0 & -1 &  2 & -1 &  0 & -1 \\
 0 &  0 &  0 &  0 & -1 &  2 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 & -1 &  2 & 0 \\
 0 &  0 & 0 &  0 &  -1 &  0 &  0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
There is one famous application in physics. Which is that a symmetric bilinear $K_{E_8}$-Chern-Simons theory describes the low energy physics of a so-called $E_8$-quantum Hall state (with a $U(1)^8$ gauge group). The field theory partition function $Z$ is given by
$$
Z= \int[DA]\exp(\frac{(K_{E_8})_{IJ}}{2 \pi}\int A_I dA_J).
$$
This $E_8$-quantum Hall state occurs in a 2-dimensional spatial condensed matter system. This describes an **invertible TQFT**. Since the $|Z|$ on any closed 3-manifold  of $M^2 \times S^1$ has $|Z|=|\det K_{E_8}|=1$. Which means the Hilbert space on any spatial closed $M^2$ is always 1-dimensional.

> **Proposal**:
>
> 3d Chern-Simons TQFT of gauge group (E8)$_1$ = SO(16)$_1 \otimes$ a trivial spin TQFT = Cartan E$_8$ matrix
>
> **My questions**: Physically, the above three theories should be the same. This means that the low energy TQFT of the above three describe the exact same physical phenomena and same physical observables.
>
> **How do we see they are the same (or at least related) from a
>    mathematical rigorous viewpoint? Any References?**

If you find what I propose is not obvious or rigorous to mathematicians, please feel free to improve my statements in your answer/comment -- thanks!